# Is it possible to get example sentences with the words' translations from Reverso Context using the requests module?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I need to get example sentences with the words' translations from [Reverso Context](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/cat).

Firstly, I tried to get the whole results page data:

```
import requests


print(requests.get("https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/cat").text)
```

And I have a problem here - the server knows I'm accessing it via a bot: my app doesn't get what I need and get this among other things:

```
<p class="text" id="text-en" style="display: none">
          You've been denied access â IP blacklisted<br/>
          Your IP <b class="ip"></b> has been considered as sending illegitimate traffic to our servers.<br/>
          If you think your traffic is legitimate, please fill in the form below so we could investigate why you were blacklisted.<br/><br/>
          Thank you,<br/>
          The Reverso Team
</p>
```

Is there a way to trick the server and get the page with examples?

P.S.: I tried to find a Python API for this web-site, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try changing the user agent in your request headers to make yourself look like a normal web browser. See https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.4/user/quickstart/#custom-headers, Google user agent headers.

Answer (score 3):

Once you're able to access the website you can find the example sentences like this.

```
req = requests.get("https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/cat", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

sentences = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'text'}) if '\n' in x.text]

>>> sentences[:4]
['My cat stepped on the remote.', 'Я не смотрю твои бредни, мой кот наступил на пульт.', 'Now imagine you have a cat...', 'А теперь представьте, что у вас есть кот...']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! :) You helped me a lot!